# how should i change my jquery script to animate mobile menu when first clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

i have the following mobile menu code i have been using for a while. it works fine. i have an animation via css added so when the menu button is clicked it adds an animation for a smooth scroll - however i am noticing it does not work on the very fist click - all clicks after the first does work. also if you see something gross in my jquery code do let me know, i am new to jquery and trying to learn by doing.

any help, or insight into something i am over looking, trying to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(function() {
    //show the menu when button is clicked
    jQuery('#menu_btn').click(function() {
        if(jQuery('#menu').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () {
                jQuery("#menu").css('display', 'none');
                jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'none');
            });
        } else {
            jQuery("#menu").css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow', function(){
                jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'block');
            });
        }
    });

    //close menu when X button is clicked
    jQuery('#menu_close').click(function() {
        jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () {
            jQuery("#menu").css('display', 'none');
        });
    });

    callOnResize();
});

jQuery(window).resize( function(){
    callOnResize();
});

function callOnResize() {
    var winwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (winwidth < 760) {
        jQuery( '#menu' ).css({ display: 'none' });
        jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow');
    } else if (winwidth >= 760) {
        jQuery( '#menu' ).css({ display: 'block' });
    }
}
```

the html of the menu is a very simple `ul li` view being output by wordpress

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html/css for the menu too so we can see? You should also do something like `var $menu = jQuery('#menu');` and re-use `$menu` in the code instead of defining it as `jQuery('#menu')` everywhere.

Comment: ok good point about the `var`. i have added the html for the menu but that is not related to this question as it is just a simple `ul li` menu

Comment: We need the code you're referencing in your jQuery. We need a working demo that reproduces the problem. My guess is you have some CSS or something that is conflicting. If I just put a `#menu_close` element and `#menu` element on a page, your code works just fine, so you have something else that is interfering.

Comment: Do you have a `:hover` CSS styles applied to `#menu_btn`. If you do, mobiles will activate that hover style on first tap, then on the second tap it would activate the click event. If this is the case, try removing that hover style on mobile.

Comment: no hover on css

Answer (score 0):

Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Your menu div "#menu" should not be displayed by default "display:none".

The script should be something like this:

```
jQuery('#menu_btn').click(function() {

        if(jQuery('#menu').is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery("#menu").css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow', function(){
               jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'block');
            });
     });

        } else {

            jQuery('#menu').animate({ left: '-100%' }, 'slow', function () {
                jQuery("#menu").css('display', 'none');
                jQuery('#menu_close').css('display', 'none'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: i edited your code slightly as you were missing a `);` - otherwise the code you have still does not animate the menu when i first click the menu button when page first loads. do you know why? if we can talk on chat i could show you where this code is on a live site i just don't want to publish the url since it is client sensitive.

Comment: You should add a working demo that reproduces the problem, then it'll be a lot easier to understand what's the problem exactly and what you're trying to do with your code "Including the CSS code".